# WPF xaml: Can't bind data using local

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was following [This Data Binding Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part). In Example 03, they show the following code,

```
<!-- Tutorial CODE -->

<Window.Resources>
     <local:Employee 
        x:Key="MyEmployee" EmployeeNumber="123" FirstName="John" 
       LastName="Doe" Department="Product Development" Title="QA Manager" 
    />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyEmployee}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=EmployeeNumber}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Title}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Department}" />
</Grid>
```

I've added other essential tags like `windows` and implemented the code like following

```
<!-- My CODE -->

<Window x:Class="Data_Binding_Example_03.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Data_Binding_Example_03"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Employee 
                x:Key="MyEmployee"
                EmployeeNumber="123"
                FirstName="John"
                LastName="Doe"
                Department="Product Development"
                Title="QA Manager"
        />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyEmployee}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=EmployeeNumber}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But I'm getting error

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Well. Are you sure that you have a class called `Employee` in your project?

Comment: Add the class file for Employee.. (or a reference to the DLL containing the class.)

Comment: Make sure that the DLL contains `Employee` class,or Rebuild the project(local ,if you have the project code).

Comment: No, I didn't create any class `Employee`. In the tutorial, they didn't instruct me to make a class `Employee`. They just shared the xaml code.

Comment: In Example 1 and 2, no class needed.

Comment: @RafafTahsin in example 1, he gets the data from a control and put in other control. However in example 3 he creates a object and *put* the data inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a Employee class (Employee.cs file) with this content:

```
public class Employee {
    public int EmployeeNumber {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Department {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```